# How to enclose each element of a Python list in parentheses?

Tags: python

If I have a Python list of strings of the form:

`List1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']`

How would I best approach formatting the list such that each element is enclosed in parentheses like so?:

`List1 = ['(One)', '(Two)', '(Three)', '(Four)']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use f-strings with a list comprehension:

```
List1 = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
[f'({x})' for x in List1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, You can use map and lambda functions which in my opinion is a bit cleaner. If you are interested in finding how *map* works, visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) and for *lambda*, visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).
Quoting from *w3schools*:

> The map() function executes a specified function for each item in an iterable. The item is sent to the function as a parameter.

> A lambda function is a small anonymous function. A lambda function can take any number of arguments, but can only have one expression.

```py
List2 = list( map(lambda x: f'{x}' , List1) )
```